# How to SUM duplicate values based on certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like this,

```
Name  |Exam_ID|Score
------+-------+------
Matt  |12     | 87
Matt  |12     | 85
Andy  |10     | 89
Lisa  |11     | 32
Lisa  |11     | 68
Andy  |11     | 38
Matt  |10     | 70
Lisa  |10     | 87
```

I want to SUM those score, but only those with different name and exam_id. If there's more than one same exam_id on same name, it will took the highest score. The end result I want like this:

```
Name  |Score
------+------
Matt  | 157
Andy  | 127
Lisa  | 155
```

Matt got 3 scores (87, 85, 70). But since 87 and 85 using same exam_id, I need to only take the highest score and SUM it with different score that got different exam_id which make his total score are 87+70 = 157

I've been trying using MAX, but I can't get it like that

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Exam_ID), SUM(Score) from RESULT
group by NAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two levels of aggregation:

```
select name, sum(max_score)
from (select name, exam_id, max(score) as max_score
      from result
      group by name, exam_id
     ) ne
group by name;
```

Comment: you have a missing close paren on sum. Tried editing it, but couldn't since its only one character.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to exploit the *structured* part of structured query language, and make a two-level query

```
 SELECT Name, SUM(Score) AS Score
   FROM (
              SELECT Name, Exam_ID, MAX(Score) AS Score
                FROM Result
               GROUP BY Name
        ) BestScoresPerExam
  GROUP BY Name
```

The inner query gets the best score for each exam. The outer one sums the scores.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
select name, exam_id, sum(Score) as max_score from result group by name, exam_id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!